# Hide button when last div is visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using `slice()` to show the next few batch of `.cards`. By default, 9 cards are visible, and then, when you click on `#button`, it will show the next 9 (and if you click again, the next 9, etc).

When there are no more cards to show (when all cards a visible), I want to hide the `#button`, but my approach isn't quite working and I fear I'm doing something really stupid ...

```js
$(function(){

  var x = 9;
  var btn = $("#button");

  $(btn).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x + 9;
    $('.section__card').slice(0, x).slideDown();
  });

  // hide btn if last card is visible
  if ( $(".section__card").last().is(":visible") ){
    console.log("last");
    $(btn).fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```css
.section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.card{
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 467px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.section__card:nth-child(2), .section__card:nth-child(3n-1) {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.section__card:nth-child(n+10) {
  display: none;
}

.section__cta{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="section__cta">
            <a id="button">Load more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition is reached only before the button is ever clicked, atleast in this example. Move your into the button click handler, that way the check happens everytime user clicks button.

```js
$(function(){

  var showing = 9;
  var btn = $("#button");

  $(btn).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showing += 3;
    // hide btn if last card is visible
    if (showing == 12){
      console.log("last");
      $(btn).fadeOut();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.card{
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 467px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.section__card:nth-child(2), .section__card:nth-child(3n-1) {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.section__card:nth-child(n+10) {
  display: none;
}

.section__cta{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="section__cta">
            <a id="button">Load more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. After testing the above code, on button click, it doesn't load in the next few cards (up to 9). For example, my demo has 12 `. section__card`'s, 9 are shown by default, but when clicking the button in the above demo, it hides the button, but doesn't load in the next few cards. Also, I can see that you're checking if the 12th card is showing, however, what if there's more than 12 cards? Is there a way to make this dynamic? To hide the button when the last card in parent div is visible?

Comment: I left out the `$('.section__card').slice(0, x).slideDown();` by accident thats why button click doesn't show all 12. Hopefully you could guess that was the issue.

Comment: Yes there is many ways you could make this more dynamic.  The way the you were trying is a strong possibility. I'd keep working on checking if last is visible till you get it to behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a dot missing in the classname here:

```
if ( $("section__card").last().is(":visible") ){
if ( $(".section__card").last().is(":visible") ){
```

Other than that the rest looks like it should function.

Comment: ah, you're correct. I've corrected the missed `.` in my demo and tested locally. However, the issue still persists, my button is still visible. My. `console.log()` doesn't log either, which makes me think it's not finding the correct element (or not finding anything at all)

Comment: I see, looks like theres a little problem with the nesting of the `.row`s, i think the second .row starts before the first one is closed, and then they both close; maybe thats borking the .last() , its hard to tell on the buildin thingy here.

Comment: ahno , spankied already found it (the other answer); he's right the if block is misplaced.